# Resetting column-formatted margins after \printindex

Tags: margins, indexing

When I make an index, or two, and print them at the end of a document, they show up in columns, just I would like. However, when adding further sections after the printed index, they continue  formatting under the two-column format. How can I reset the margins and layot settings to normal?

Comment: `\onecolumn` after the index?

Comment: How do you get the index? What package are you using for multiple indices?

Comment: you might try adding `\begingroup` before the first index and `\endgroup` after the second.  (the fact that the original page format isn't restored after an index sounds like a design flaw to me.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `idxlayout` or `imakeidx` packages, that modify the definition of the index related macros so that the problem of restarting to write in one column is overcome.

The `imakeidx` package also supports more than one index; its automatic feature should be disabled, though, if the further section after the indices add material to them.